# Restore pg_basebackup on Linux which was created from a Windows hosted database cluster

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql, high-availability, backup-strategies

Currently I am doing some Research on how to set up streaming replication for a HA postgresql architecture. But this issue is also relevant for us for backup/restore and maintenance in mixed environments in general.

Our "main" postgresql server is running on a Windows box. I am using pg_dump to create logical backups every day and pg_basebackup and WAL archiving to create a full backup which should provide PITR (I have not tested this yet).

Next step is to set up a slave machine which holds a replica via streaming replication. Due to the better Support of the postgresql ecosystem, this new host is running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS.

1. With `pg_basebackup -h <main host> -D <datadirectory> --xlog-method=stream` I initialized the slave datadirectory.
2. Then I had to fix some symbolic links onto tablespace files, as these were pointing on Windows paths instead of the Linux filesystem.
3. Next I created the recovery.conf file with `standby_mode = on` and the connectioninfo
4. I verified, that the Server is configured as `hot_standby = on` and started the daemon

Now I am running into issues as postgres tells me, that the **"database locale (English_United_States.1252 which is obviously Windows specific) is incompatible with operating System"**

Well, I am aware, that 1252 is a Windows specific locale and that I should use en_US.UTF8 on Linux, BUT in a mixed Environment like this, should I:

- Init our main DB on Windows also with an en_US.UTF8 locale?
- Is that even possible?
- Why is the pg_basebackup format Operating System specific, or is there a backup Format which is not?
- Is there any command line flag to set to translate this?
- I would also appreciate it to use only Linux (or even only Windows), but I am afraid our customers will rely on both Operating Systems quite a while.

Comment: Streaming replication from Pg on Windows to Linux or vice versa is not supported.

Comment: how you do the logical backup with `pg_basebackup`?.. you should use pg_dump to move from one OS to different

Comment: @VaoTsun as I have written I am doing both (pg_dump, pg_basebackup) for backup purposes. For the purpose of getting the database from one host to the other to initialize Streaming replication, I use pg_basebackup

Comment: @CraigRinger even when I move the database via pg_dump like VaoTsun is mentioning?

Comment: then @CraigRinger comment is the best answer

Comment: streaming replication requires binary safe copy of datafile - `pg_backup` or `rsync` - another os wont just take such files. pg_dump doesn't copy file - only data and thus cant be used for streaming replication

Comment: `pg_dump` isn't `pg_basebackup`. You should be able to use `pg_dump`, but you were talking about `pg_basebackup` above.

Comment: as I tagged my question with "backup-strategies" and "high-availability" and I asked questions pointing on these aspects, I thank you for your suggestions. A clear answer like Laurenz did seems to be possible according to my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot restore file system backups like the one that `pg_basebackup` creates on a different architecture, like restore a backup from Windows on Linux.

It is also impossible to have streaming repication in such a scenario.

From PostgreSQL v10 on, you might consider logical replication.

Comment: thanks for clarification, I was afraid this is the case. Also thanks a lot for suggesting pglogical (https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/) which I will further research on as an extension to postgres-9.6

Comment: I won't say anything against pglogical, but it is different from logical replication as shipped with v10. If you can wait until then, I'd do that.